# What was the structure of first course in sociology?

Tags: academia, social-sciences

I read that Max Weber supported the anti-positivist approach to sociology in Ludwig Maxmilian University of Munich. So I want to know the academic structure of the first course he appealed for. I doubt if it is possible to answer this but I believe some experienced men will give an answer  as much it is possible to give. I want to know this because I have to start myself in Sociology and I don't want to do it in wrong way.